# Is there a Macro to hide all sheets in a workbook when a certain cell is equal to 100%?

Tags: excel, vba

I understand the logic behind this but I'm unsure how to right the macro. I import up to 63 sheets of data into excel.

ALL of the sheets have a status in Column B Row 9. I would like to make a macro to hide all sheets in the workbook when B9 = 100%

```
If Worksheet.Column.B, Row.9= 100%
Worksheet.hide
```

Comment: The title of your question is a bit misleading. a) you cannot hide ALL of the worksheets in any workbook; one must remain visible. b) from your accepted answer, it seems that you want to hide *each* worksheet when *that* worksheet's B9 is 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the VB Editor <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.  Under `Microsoft Excel Objects` right click Insert --> Module.  Paste in the following code.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideSheets()

        Dim ws As Worksheet

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                If ws.Range("B9").Value = 1 Then
                        ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                End If
        Next ws

End Sub
```

The `Option Explicit` setting forces you to declare variables.  I include this because, on top of good coding practice, it has saved me hours of debugging only to find I spelled a variable name wrong (such errors are captured before the code begins when adding this line).

The basic principle is that the code uses a `For..Each` loop to iterate through each worksheet in the workbook.  IF cell `B9` is 1 (corresponding to 100%) then the worksheet's `Visible` property is set to `xlSheetHidden` which hides the sheet.  Sheets with this visible property can be unhidden if the user right-clicks along the worksheet tabs and selects `Unhide...`.  If you don't want users to be able to unhide the sheets, you can set it to `xlSheetVeryHidden` which hides the sheet and disabled unhiding the sheet from the UI.

To run this macro you can click anywhere inside the code and click the button that looks like play (this is the Run Sub/Userform button) or you can press <kbd>F5</kbd>.

I would recommend setting the macro to a keyboard shortcut, or if you prefer to a button located somewhere on the worksheet.

To assign the macro a keyboard shortcut:

- Under the Developer tab select Macros (or simply press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) to display the Macro window
- Under `Macro name:` select the name of your macro (`HideSheets` in this example)
- Click `Options...`
- Put the key in that you want to press to run the macro (in this case I chose <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for hide)
- Select `OK`
- Test by pressing the keyboard combination you specified

Additionally, you can assign a macro to run when a button on the worksheet is clicked, to do this:

- Under Developer go to the Insert dropdown
- Under ActiveX controls, select the command button
- Draw the button anywhere on the page
- Right click the button --> CommandButton Object --> Edit
- Change the button text to whatever you want (like `Hide Sheets` for example)
- Double click the button to open the code, you should see a `Sub` entitled `CommandButton1_Click()`
- Type `HideSheets` into the subroutine like this (or whatever the name of your subroutine is)

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
          HideSheets
  End Sub
  ```
- Exit design mode by clicking Design Mode under the Developer tab
- Click the button to ensure the macro functions

Comment: Thanks Soulfire for the elaborate explanation and useful practices for the future. The "B9" column actually displays 100.00% when complete. I've tried typing that into your code and it's not working for some reason. Any ideas ?

Comment: Very thorough answer but I find the `... = 100` to be misleading. 100% typically has a [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) or [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) of **1** or a [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) of **100%**. It would rarely have a value of 100 and is most likely bad worksheet design if it did.

Comment: I did specify that it may be either 100 or 1, depending on the formatting of the cell in my answer.  I can change or add a comment in the code maybe, I do agree in general a 100% is likely to be specified as a 1.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Soulfire, you can run the **automatically** anytime the value in the cell changes value. Just put the following code under the worksheet (not the module), which will run the macro 'HideSheets' whenever the value in cell C9 changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
        Call HideSheets
    End If

End Sub
```